# How to Plot Graphs in Julia 0.5?

Tags: plot, julia, juno-ide

I'm learning Julia by working through [Chris Rackauckas' Introduction](http://ucidatascienceinitiative.github.io/IntroToJulia/) and I've come across a task that requires me to plot some data.  I couldn't manage to get the Plots module to import so I tried a simple test:

```
using Plots
x = 1:10
y = 0.5*x + 3
plot(x, y)
```

When I first run this piece of code using the Juno IDE I get an error:

```
LoadError: LoadError: LoadError: syntax: unhandled expr (error #<julia: Main.Base.MethodError(f=FixedPointNumbers.#floattype(), args=(Main.FixedPointNumbers.FixedPoint{UInt8, 8},))>)
in include_from_node1(::String) at .\loading.jl:488 (repeats 2 times)
in eval(::Module, ::Any) at .\boot.jl:234
in require(::Symbol) at .\loading.jl:415
in include_string(::String, ::String) at .\loading.jl:441
in include_string(::Module, ::String, ::String) at 2
```

This refers to the using statement in my snippet.  This error does not appear when I run from the REPL.  The version info is as follows:

**Julia Version 0.5.0**
Commit 3c9d753 (2016-09-19 18:14 UTC)
**Platform Info:**
System: NT (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4810MQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
WORD_SIZE: 64
BLAS: libopenblas (USE64BITINT DYNAMIC_ARCH NO_AFFINITY Haswell)
LAPACK: libopenblas64_
LIBM: libopenlibm
LLVM: libLLVM-3.7.1 (ORCJIT, haswell)

I currently have version 0.10.3 of Plots installed.

Comment: You may need to `Pkg.update()` and restart the REPL in order to make sure your packages are up to date.

Comment: @Chris As this only appears to happen when I run from Juno it could be that they do something like this in the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To work with the Run File command using the Juno package in the Atom IDE the plot has to be assigned to a variable and passed to the `display` function.

```
using Plots
pyplot()
x = 1:100
y = 0.5*x + 10
println(y)
graph = plot(x, y)
display(graph)
```

This will display the graph in Juno's Plots window.  In the comments Arda Aytekin suggested that `pyplot(display=true)` or `graph = plot(x, y, display=true)` could be used, which leads to the graph displaying in a separate pyplot window.

Comment: you can even have `pyplot(display=true)` to override the default setting. or, `plot(x,y,display=true)`, maybe. please check these options, too, and modify your answer accordingly. Then, please mark your answer as the solution for future reference :)

Answer (score 2):

If you provide some version/platform information by sharing the output of `versioninfo()`, one can help you better.

For instance, the below excerpt

```
Pkg.add("Plots")
using Plots
plotly() # this backend is installed by default
x = 1:10
y = 0.5*x + 3
plot(x, y)
```

works well under

```
Julia Version 0.5.0
Commit 3c9d753* (2016-09-19 18:14 UTC)
Platform Info:
  System: Linux (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3720QM CPU @ 2.60GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  BLAS: libopenblas (NO_LAPACK NO_LAPACKE NO_AFFINITY SANDYBRIDGE)
  LAPACK: liblapack
  LIBM: libm
  LLVM: libLLVM-3.7.1 (ORCJIT, ivybridge)
```

Maybe you should conisder `Pkg.add("PyPlot")` or a similar backend, and try it again later?

Comment: Just tried your suggestion and got a similar error for both Plotly and PyPlots.  Is the version info satisfactory?

Comment: @RHP are you using `workspace()` in any part of your code? might be related to [this issue](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/issues/576), maybe?

Comment: I been experimenting with this a little more and found that the test code works fine in the REPL the problem only exists in Juno IDE.  I'll modify my question to reflect this.

Comment: Worked it out, I needed to add a display command for it to work with Juno's run file command.